# Передачи файлов от клиента серверу.

Tags: c#, fileupload

Привет.

Есть задача, организовать передачу файлов от клиента (программы установленной на PC пользователя) на сервер. Учитывая, что все должно быть секьюрно и информация о загруженном файле должна добавиться в БД, то у меня созрел следующий вопрос.

1. Какой протокол посоветуете использовать?(кроме http/https)

Я склоняюсь к **sftp** (ну чтоб и безопасность заодно обеспечить, вот только не пойму как в таком случае уведомлять БД о переданном файле?
Да и отмечу, что размер передаваемого файла может быть **даже больше 10ГБ**. Меньше не устраивает.

В принципе, это что-то схожее с сервисами Dropbox и Google Drive.
При этом насколько я знаю у Dropbox проприетарный протокол, а у аналогичных (Drive и т.д ) как то все засекречено и информации никакой в интернете не нашел.

Comment: Если эти сервисы используют sftp, то скорее всего у них свои сервера, которые обрабатывают прием файлов по своему. Замечу то, что файл от клиента, насколько я знаю, передается в данных программах кусками.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что они используют sftp, более того я даже считаю, что они его не используют. Я тоже считаю, что передаются кусками.

Comment: Если верить английской википедии, то Dropbox использует librsync, а значит, [передает блоками разницу между файлами](http://citforum.ru/nets/articles/rsync/). Опять таки вариант - просто использовать rsync over ssh.

Comment: хм..это уже интересно, щас покопаюсь. Спасибо.

Comment: @eigenein, пожалуйста, добавьте Ваш комментарий к ответу, чтобы я его принял. Т.к это то что нужно. Вы дали этот комментарий раньше, чем уважаемый ToRcH565, поэтому мне хотелось бы принять именно Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовать клиент серверное приложение(и клиент и сервер) со своим протоколом поблочной передачи файла, используюя свой собственный(любой готовый чужой) симметричный алгоритм шифрования с ключем зависящим от айди сессии,с обновлением только измененных блоков файла(отслеживать можно хэш суммами куска файла).

Гарантирована секурность,

Answer (score 0):

> (кроме http/https)

Обоснуете?

В целом мне представляется все так: на сервере висит веб-приложение, держит коннект к базе и слушает HTTPS. Когда приходит POST - заливает файл из тела запроса в базу.

Если задача заключается только в отправке файлов в базу, то MongoDB, навпример, поддерживает файловую систему на уровне базы. Можно пробросить SSH-туннель или VPN, и заливать через [mongofiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongofiles/).

Comment: Коннектов будет очень много. И файлы  размер 10Гб и более врядли правильно передавать через http. Вэб серверы такую нагрузку врядли выдержат.

Comment: Есть какие-то бенчмарки/тесты скорости? Есть какие-то принципиальные различия в затрате ресурсов на HTTP и не-HTTP подключения?

Comment: Спасибо, что Вы любезно стараетесь мне помочь, я очень это ценю, честно, но давайте не будем идти так далеко, пожалуйста. Мне абсолютно не хочется что либо доказывать, я прошу совета у людей, уже построивших или знающих в этой области (при этом я ни в коем случае не умоляю Ваших знаний). Но использовать http для таких целей я не буду. Я ведь указал это в вопросе.